# Shift array to the right by one slot

Tags: java, arrays

This might be already answered but I've looked for a while and this is what all of the solutions say to do. Please redirect me to the right thread if it's already been answered.

The concept is simple. I need to shift each element of the array over to the right by one place. This has to be done from an index that is provided by the user. Here's what should happen:

> **Expected output**
>   {0, 1, 2, 3} --> add(4 (element), 1 (location)) --> {0, 4, 1, 2, 3}

However when testing my code, I got results like this:

> **Actual results**
>   
> {0, 1, 2, 3} --> add(4, 1) --> {0, 4, 1, 1, 1}

Here is my code:

```
private void shiftRight(int index) 
{
  assert !isFull();

  for(int i = index; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
  {
    elements[i + 1] = elements[i];
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm super close to solving this problem. Like I don't think there's a big issue but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It looks like you're using an array when what you _want_ is a list. Why not use a list (like an ArrayList, or Vector, or any other implementation of List that has an insert method)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans a list would be better, but for the sake of this project, I have to use an array

Comment: In that case, you probably want to learn about [System.arrayCopy](https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-system-arraycopy-method)

Comment: You copy the second element which is `1` to the third element which becomes `1`, then you copy the third element which is now `1` to the fourth element and continue to copy the same value over and over again

Comment: This should crash with an index-out-of-bounds error when i = (elements.length - 1)

Comment: @Oleg I notice that now, that makes perfect sense, I'll look into a way to store the next item in the list before copying, or maybe going from a different direction might help

Comment: Or create an array that is larger than you need, and manage the size yourself.

Answer (score 2):

When you are going to shift elements to the right, you can't walk through the array from left to right since you would overwrite values on the next array spot. I also noticed you wrote "i < elements.length - 1". You probably shouldn't add the -1, or you will skip the last value in the array (unless you want that).

First of all, make sure your array has enough space (you will need 1 more), if you are working with primitive types. Therefor you need to create a second array.

Example:

```
int[] array = new int[prevValue+1];
```

Now you will have to shift the values to the right, to prevent overwriting the next value we start from the right and go to the left (depends on whether you use the same array or a different array).

```
for (int i = array.length-1; i >= startPos; i--) {
     elements[i+1] = array[i];
}
```

Then on the extra spot you reserved you can set a new value:

```
elements[startPos]=value;
```

Last but not least, you will have to fill your previous elements (if you are using the same array you can ignore this).

```
for (int i = 0; i < startPos; i++) {
   elements[i] = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is where your problem is:

```
for(int i = index; i < elements.length - 1; i++)
{
    elements[i + 1] = elements[i];
}
```

Lets take your example.

`{0, 1, 2, 3}` `i = 1`

You set `elements[i + 1]`, or `elements[2]` to `elements[1]`. So, you're new array is `{0, 1, 1, 3}`. So far so good. But now, when you set 3 to the current number, you set that to the thing you set before. So you will get `{0, 1, 1, 1}`. The way to avoid this is to iterate from the right, so numbers won't get lost.